# Trouble loading static files in Nginx + Digital Ocean Deployment

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, nginx, gunicorn

Django Beginner here..

Having some trouble loading my static files during final deployment on a Digital Ocean Droplet

I'm using Nginx and Gunicorn.

I've followed a tutorial from Traversy Media, but I can not get my static files to show up in the browser via my Digital Ocean ipv4. Upon inspecting it is throwing these multiple errors.

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://162.243.162.127/btre/static/css/all.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

```
GET 162.243.162.127/:510 GET http://162.243.162.127/btre/static/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Here are my nginx settings

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 162.243.162.127;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/djangoadmin/pyapps/realestate_project;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/djangoadmin/pyapps/realestate_project;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Here are my gunicorn settings

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=djangoadmin
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/realestate_project
ExecStart=/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          btre.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've tried running collectstatic in the terminal multiple times but it does not do anything.. Says it has '0 to collect'.

[image]

Comment: do you have files directly in `realestate_project` or in `realestate_project/static`

Comment: you define `location /static/` but error shows `http://162.243.162.127/btre/static/` - as for me it should be `location /btre/static/`

Comment: Any reason why the admin side of the site would not load the static files?

Answer (score 1):

I recreated the problem in my localhost and it turns out that I needed to add the project folders app's name before the '/static/' URL location in Nginx, like it is in my project folders app's 'settings.py'.

sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/btre_project

change:

/static/

to:

/my_app/static

Comment: Not sure why this works since on my another server I did not append project name